# What is the proper way to handle FB.Event.subscribe?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to record whenever a user clicks on Facebook Like button. Facebook documentation even [specifically mentions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) this possibility:

"suppose you want to record Likes in your database whenever a button is clicked":

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

It then tells you to "replace the alert() with your handling code." Is there a proper way to create this handling code? How would it be called? I tried searching for some easy solution, but haven't been successful. The problem is I am not familiar with JavaScript, but it shouldn't be this hard to find what I presume is a one-line solution.

UPDATE: I understand that I have to call a separate script to actually interact with the database. I am just not sure how to call it exactly and if the Facebook JavaScript SDK provides any assistance with that. Based on the first answer I received, I should use something like jQuery, but that seems a bit of an overkill to me. Am I wrong in that assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need more than one line, because you will need a database to record it in as well.  You would use an ajax call to a page you have setup to record the click event.  The easiest ajax call to setup is jquery's IMO.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  But you still need something to submit to on the server side to record your click, such as an asp or php page with a sql or mysql database, or even a text file on the server.

Comment: I understand that I must call another page to actually perform the action. I am just not sure how to call that page. Do I have to use a framework such as jQuery? There is no way to do that with a simple plain JavaScript function?